# mule org.json.JSONObject returning property value as null though the json property does have value for it

Tags: mule, org.json

I am using the below code to convert the input payload string to json in mule. The below code sometimes working and sometimes not. its not working on standalone and working on studio. Not able to nail down the exact cause for it. but based on the loggers that i see that the property value is coming null after the expression statement. i am suspecting this could be with the jar that's getting used here. i am still digging further on it.

```
<logger message="input: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
         <set-payload value="#[payload.'data']" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Set Payload" encoding="ISO-8859-2"/>
        <logger message="createConnection: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[String input = payload;    

payload = new org.json.JSONObject(input);
]]></expression-component>
<logger message="before json to object: #[payload.con_id] #[payload.'con_id']" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
```

Input JSON:

```
data: {"name":"QA_tst2","description":"tst","con_id":10,"con_connection_id":null,
"verticalParam":[{"param_value":"abc","param_name":"Host"},{"param_value":"21","param_name":"Port"}],"CON_CATEGORY_NAME":"File"}
```

Comment: Which part is not working? What is your expected output? If the input string is in JSON format, all you need to do is set the mime type and Mule will treat it as JSON.

Comment: after the expression component, its returning the con_id values as null. instead it should give 10. you can see my input  json. we already have the MIME type setup as application/json. when we initially faced this problem by fetching con_id as payload.con_id then we had swtiched the code to payload.'con_id' then it was giving the desired output. now both of the options are not working. and the challenge is we have the code like this at many places through out my flows. hence the reason, i would like to understand the root cause of this issue and figure out accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the current issue. if there is any logger added to fetch the properties from the payload right after the expression component then its screwing up further. if you just remove the logger that was added after the expression component then after json to object conversion, i am able to fetch the values. that solves the current issue. but i would like to understand the difference between fetching the properties #[payload.con_id] vs #[payload.'con_id']. i can start a separate conversation for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that notation will work for JSONObject, try using

```
payload.get('con_id')
```

as per the javadoc: https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html.

The reason this won't work with the notation you have tried, is that Mule supports that notation for Maps, and org.json.JSONObject does not implement java.util.Map. You could try using [javax.json.JSONObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) instead, which will support that notation.

Comment: Ciinton, Thanks for the Suggestion!. i will definitely review this. but this is not happening in studio. this happens only on mule standalone. how do we can replicate this on local at least to make sure this is the actual cause.

Comment: I tried this in studio only, and I got the result that you describe here. I was only able to get the correct value by using payload.get on the JSON object.